# fwrite not working on last iteration

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I'm just trying to get a set of numbers ordered (while the code I'm posting is not the approach I'm going to use, I do need to write to a binary file the output as done in the code).
Everything works fine, except for the last iteration of "ordenar": when I print back again the numbers after ordering, everything is ordered except for the last line, I have verified that ordenar is done correctly, and the `fwrite()` in that very last iteration is returning a value of 10, but it seems as if it does not write that last output.

Code is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define SIZE 10
#define MAX  10

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numbers[SIZE];


int genera_numeros() {
    unsigned long i, j;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("number.dat", "wb");
    if (!file) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;    
    }

    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            numbers[j] = rand()%1000;
            printf("%i ", numbers[j]);
        }
        fwrite(numbers, sizeof(int), SIZE, file);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
} 


int imprime_numeros() {
    unsigned long i, j;
    int numbers[SIZE];
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("number.dat", "rb");
    if (!file) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        fread(numbers, sizeof(int), SIZE, file);
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%i ",numbers[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}


int ordenar(FILE* file, long int num_bloque)
{
    int byte=0, written=0;
    fseek(file, num_bloque * sizeof(int) * SIZE, SEEK_SET);
    fread(numbers, sizeof(int), SIZE, file);
    qsort (numbers, SIZE, sizeof(int), compare);
    fseek(file, num_bloque * sizeof(int) * SIZE, SEEK_SET);
    byte=ftell(file);
    written=fwrite(numbers, sizeof(int), SIZE, file);
    return 0;
} 


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
        file = fopen("number.dat", "rb+");
    long int i;

    genera_numeros();
    printf("\n\n Los numeros son:\n\n");
    imprime_numeros();
    printf("\n\n Ordenando...");

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {   
        ordenar(file, i);
    }

    printf("\n\n Los numeros son:\n\n");
    imprime_numeros();
    printf("\n");

    fclose(file);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You open the file at the beginning, then open/close it during `genera` and `imprime`. I am pretty sure that is a bad idea. What happens if you wait with the opening of `file` in the `main` program until just before the sort loop?

Comment: You should avoid posting large blocks of code. Always try to prepare [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to do it

Comment: And you just forgot to tell about that segfault part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, because I can't tell what exactly your code is supposed to do, remove what gives you segfault.
You close you `file` both with `imprime_numeros()` and the in `main()`.
Remove one or aother and your program works.

Here's my solution to your problem with not sorting last row. Just make one more iteration with

```
for(i=0;i<MAX+1;i++){
```

and it works. I'm currently looking into "why" part of solution.
**EDIT 1**
It took me a while, but here it goes:
in your main() you have `FILE* file=fopen(..)` and that's the only place you don't check if it opens correctly. Every first time your program runs- it doesn't find that file and `file` in main() in set to NULL.
Then it merrily proceeds and calls functions `genera_numeros()` that opens its own file(and creates numbers.dat btw...) but on the local scope, since outside `genera_numeros()` `file` is still NULL.
And so it creates a file, fills it and proceeds to `imprima_numeros()` that opens previously created `numbers.dat`(still on local scope and you close this file after use).
Then goes the `ordenar` part and things start to get interesting.
`ordenar(file, i)` takes your NULL file and...crashes with segmentation fault.
(**interesting** part, and what tricked me, was this will **NOT** occure second time you run the program, because `numbers.dat` will remain from previous run).

**EDIT 2. FINAL**
Yes, I just spent 2 non-paid-late-nigt hours in finding bug in someone else's code. I might be that guy...Anyway...
Problem is with multiple opening of the same file.
Bu that I mean, when you fix previous bug with opening non-existent file, or just run program 2nd time you open a file in main() then open and close this file few times with `imprime_numeros` and `genera_numeros`. That's supposed to be `implementation-defined` behavior.
Problem is that after your last call to `ordenar()` in your loop you re-open it with `imprime_numeros` and written last sorted line is not yet visible in your file on disk. This will be done after you close the file stream. So you see state of the file just before writing sorted last line to it.

Now why my `MAX+1` solution worked is that it forced to write last line permamently so it was visible in your file opened by `imprime_numeros()`. 
That's **almost** all.
Notice that by adding MAX+1 you get file of 440 bytes in size( i have 4 byte int) and it's supposed to be 400.
I also forgot to mention how to fix the problem, but you can propably track that down by my description.
**Hint**
fclose(file) before reading from it.

All who are reading this answer to this point, I will be thankful for editing it for grammar, style. It's late and this one cost me a lot.

Comment: I did forget to check if the files opens in main(), however I will make sure that this file always exists.
About last ieration not being sorted, I still don't know why this happens, but I noticed that the one that was not happening was not the last one, but the very first one.
I was able to fix it by moving fopen and fclose in main right before and after ther sorting loop respectively.
Can anybody explain me why this happens?

Comment: @AdrianSalgado Read my 2nd update. Final, I suppose. Wait, one more to go.

Comment: @AdrianSalgado Here you go. All debugged and explained.

Comment: Sure! Thank you very much! I guess YES... you are that guy. It was a great explanation, I appreciate your time, because you could just give me the solution, but instead you used your time to make me understand what I was doing wrong.